# Routing Conundrum

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

I have quite a strange problem. In my angular app my routing module is mixing up components. So if I put in the address for component-x it will take me instead to component-y. If I change the order of the route object the route that same address suddently goes to the right component or even sometimes it can't find the component at all.

I tried making all the variables in the path's unque, adding  pathMatch: 'full', runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always' and even stripping all everything down to a standard implementation. I upgraded from 10 -12 hoping it would fix itself but alas!

Here is my code:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent },
    // Shope Pages
    // ------------------------
    { path: ':catCompCategory/:catCompCategoryChild' , component: CategoryComponent },
    { path: ':catParCompCategory' , component: CategoryParentComponent },
    { path: 'checkout' , component: CheckoutComponent },
    { path: 'filter/:condition/:value/:parameter' , component: FilteredProductsComponent },
    { path: ':singleProdCompCategory/:singleProdCompCategoryChild/:singleProdCompProductName' , component: SingleProductComponent },
    { path: 'view-all/:allCompCategory' , component: ViewAllComponent },
    // General Pages
    // ------------------------
    { path: 'help-center/about-us', component: AboutUsComponent },
    { path: 'bounce', component: BounceComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'help-center/contact-us', component: ContactUsComponent },
    { path: 'help-center/faq', component: FaqComponent },
    { path: 'help-center/order-tracking', component: OrderTrackingComponent },
    { path: 'help-center/privacy-policy', component: PrivacyPolicyComponent },
    { path: 'help-center/returns', component: ReturnsComponent },
    { path: 'help-center/terms-conditions', component: TermsConditionsComponent },
    // Payfast
    // ------------------------
    { path: 'payfast/cancel', component: CancelComponent },
    { path: 'payfast/notify', component: NotifyComponent },
    { path: 'payfast/success', component: SuccessComponent }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
            anchorScrolling: 'enabled',
            onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload',
            useHash: true
        }
    )],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class RoutingModule {}
```

Here are my typescript settings:

```
"baseUrl": "./",
 "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
 "importHelpers": true,
 "sourceMap": true,
 "declaration": false,
 "downlevelIteration": true,
 "experimentalDecorators": true,
 "moduleResolution": "node",
 "target": "es2017",
 "module": "es2020",
 "lib": [
 "es2018",
 "dom"
        ],
 "typeRoots": [
 "node_modules/@types",
 "./typings.d.ts"
        ],
 "resolveJsonModule": true,
 "esModuleInterop": true,
 "skipLibCheck": true
```

I'm sure it's starting at me right in the face, but I'd really appreciate some help on this! Thank you so much

Comment: very cute - but instead of component-x / component-y can you be more specific what the problem is? Also, you may want to remove imports - they don't help in understanding your code. Also, you say that you "stripp[ed] all everything down to a standard implementation" (whatever that means). That would be closer to minimal viable example - can you show that?

Comment: hi @Felix. What I meant was if for example I go to _/help-center/contact-us_ expecting it to take me to _ContactUsComponent_ it will take me the to the _CategoryComponent_ (as above). If move the component/path settings in the route object it navigates to another component entirely.

What I meant by a standard implementation is not having any extra parameter in the route options: imports: _[RouterModule.forRoot(routes)]_. I hope that is clearer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have routes defined with only route params this is the behavior you get. This is why it is bad practice to not have a constant path and have only route params.

Quick hack fix is to move any routes that start with params to the end of the routes array.

The real fix is to add a constant to the beginning of those routes. Such as “category/something/something-else” for the category component.